# Excel Chart doesn't keep format

Tags: excel, charts, number-formatting

I have a table (came from a pivot table) where I have formatted the column 4 cells to show 1 billion as 1. But when I select the table and insert a chart, I am getting my units in millions. So the 14.8 billion number for Mexico is showing up as 14,800 on the chart. Why might this be happening and how can I fix this? This is also making all my other bars negligibly small. Note that the first three columns are not in billions and are totally different things. Some are percentages, some are other small numbers.

**Table:**

[image]

**Chart:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a secondary horizontal axis and some formatting on the Axes.

In Excel 2013

First change the Chart Type to Combo and select Clustered Bar for both sets of data, then Check 
Secondary Axis for the Percentage Series.
[image]

Then set up the axis limits so they match, e.g.

Percentage: min -.5 max 2

Billions: min -5e9 max 20e9

Then set the percentage format on the source data to a custom Number format of "";(0)%;0%

[image]

Then set the Billions format as 0,,,;"";0

[image]

You will get something like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

Now that we have the general principles, we can apply them to your specific data.

I will also switch to **Excel 2010** do show the different menus.

The data selection looks like this

[image]

Select the non-Billion series (plural!) and check the secondary axis

[image]

If the larger data is always positive then you can use custom formatting to clean up the axis

[image]

Align the primary and secondary axes so that the grid lines match on both

[image]
[image]

The end result is clean and readable.

Mixing percentages and numbers for the smaller numbers is not handled by this but I would suggest that that would be confusing anyway?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts I just show the principle and I'm sure the OP can figure out how to extend to add other series and appropriate labels

Comment: @pnuts `I hope you did not feel obliged to switch to 2010 'cos of my comment.`  well, maybe a little :)  I thought it was a good point actually... On your last point, my experience with these things (having operated a human brain for quite a while now) is that the explaining around can switch a light on or break the mental log jam so hopefully the OP will navigate themselves to an acceptable conclusion.

Comment: @pnuts ah well... if we all agreed life would be far less interesting :)  `my colour scheme is prettier.`  mmmk, "equally dissonant, I would allow" any criticism of my color scheme you will have to direct at MS... and anyway... as we say in Australia: beauty is in the eye of the beer holder  ;)

Comment: @CoolBlue OMG!! You rock. You should write a book or be a teacher!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix this might be to plot cells containing the billions values divided by 10^9 rather than to plot the billions themselves, though via a secondary axis may be possible.

Using Excel 2007. For the purple bars, the example on the left uses ColumnE values, on the right ColumnF values. E1 contains `=F1/10^9` and F1 contains `=14800000000`:

[image: SO20887139 example]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that *there are 3 questions here*: 1) "Why might this be happening", 2) "how can I fix this", and 3) something like "how can I plot data which lie on two widely differing ranges, and make them all reasonably visible anyway", even if there was no explicit question on this.

There are several ways to solve *issue #2* about the units (e.g., billions) and numbers (e.g., 14.8 vs. 14,800.0) shown in the axis, each one with its own pros and cons:

1. Use Format Axis -> Axis Options -> Display units.

   This might be the answer to your *issue #1* as well, you might have the following selection: Display units -> Millions, and unchecked Show display units... Otherwise, I wouldn't know why you chart shows what it shows.
2. Use faked tick marks, as indicated in the (excellent) site of Jon Peltier

   http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ArbitraryAxis.html

   It gives detailed instructions on how to create tick marks on an axis with arbitrary labels (which may be text, numbers, etc.), which is more generic than what the OP wants here. In this particular case, the labels will be the desired numbers.
3. Create new cells containing data that would be plotted exactly the way you want.

As for your *issue #3*, I guess the only option is to have a Secondary Axis (see the answer by pnuts).

Thus, to come up with the best final chart for you might use a combination of one of the options I gave here and a secondary axis.

Comment: @pnuts - I elaborated a bit. I guess there is no point in explaining more than this, any further step should be tried, hands on.

Comment: @pnuts Correct. My answer shows a technique to overcome this problem

Comment: @pnuts Fair comment! I have modified my answer based on your feed-back. Actually the principles I outlined in my original answer can be applied to deliver the desired result. Three types of data (small numbers, percentages AND billions) is not achievable with a secondary axis but I would argue that it is not good practice anyway.  Thanks again for your feed-back  :)

Comment: @pnuts - I have expanded, and disaggregated the questions asked in an attempt to fully address all what was asked. I think that 1- or 2- are As to part of *this multiple* Q (and I agree in that they are not As to the other part of the Q, for which there is a different A).

Comment: @pnuts - That is what I called Q#3. Q#2 only referred to units, regardless of the data laying on two different ranges. And my A1 and A2 address Q#2. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Everything you say is correct and understandable. That point (Q#3) is addressed with the Secondary Axis, as you suggested. Q#2 ("how can I fix this") refers to a different issue, and that is the target of most of my answer.