# Chart doesn't keep data label number formattng

Tags: excel

I am having a problem with my data label formatting within an excel chart. As can be seen in the image below, the chart isn't retaining the number formatting I have set in the columns B and C.

I have used conditional formatting to make it so that if a number is below 0.01 it is displayed as a scientific e.g. 5.E-05 to 2 DP. And I've also got another rule that keeps all the numbers to 2DP if they are over 0.01.

I've already tried to link the formatting back to the sources of the cells but it gives me the same results e.g. Format Data Labels >> Number >> Linked to source (ticked).

The reason I do not do this manually is because its part of a python automation project, and it would also defeat the object of my conditional formatting.

I've already seen the solution for this question but the answer was to manual change it and again wouldn't allow me to use my conditional formatting.

[Excel Chart doesn't keep format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887139/excel-chart-doesnt-keep-format)

See link for image below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/45gmvtjqgd0y8e0/thing.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update : It seems that my conditional formatting is getting in the way when i disable it, it allows the chart to be linked to the data. However I need numbers below 0.01 to be displayed as 1E-3 etc so this doesn't solve the problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Conditional Formatting you can use custom number formatting which should flow through to the chart.

1. Select cells you want to format
2. Right Click > `Format Cells`
3. On the `Number` tab, select `Custom`
4. In the `Type:` field enter the following

   [<0.01]0.E+00;0.00

This will format anything less than .01 as Scientific, and anything else by a number with 2 decimal points.

Comment: I've just implemented this and a problem that arises is that when I paste into the cells (Part of my python automation using openpyxl), it doesn't keep the format, whereas it did with the conditional formatting...any advice?

Comment: In addition to this I cannot use a macro because the python module I am using doesn't support macros.

Comment: You could have your python code paste in one place, then you could use formulas to have it pull to your formatted section.

Comment: You can also right click on the axis (of the chart) and custom format the axis only.